# g++ error, unrecognized option, --subsystem console" in eclipse in ubuntu

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, gcc, g++

I have ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32bit installed correctly. I am facing a problem when i build my project.

I install everything correctly, i.e gcc, g++ and other libraries required. when I build my project it builds, but when I clean it, and want to build it again it does not build and give error "g++ error, unrecognized option, --subsystem console".
i have eclipse indigo which is built in ubuntu 12.04 LTS. gcc4.6, g++ 4.6, jdk1.6 all are installed correctly.

Comment: GCC doesn't have such an option `--subsystem`. Why do you have it?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Looks like the `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` option MSVC uses.

Comment: It looks like eclipse is misconfigured and assumes you're using mingw instead of native gcc. There should be a linker option -Wl,--subsystem,console , or -mconsole (alternative is -Wl,--subsystem,windows  or -mwindows) on mingw which lets you build with or without a console window (useful for winapi based applications). Apparently ubuntu's native gcc does not accept these parameters.

Comment: @nurettin    thanks for quick reply. then how will i solve this problem in ubuntu?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg   i don't know that why i facing this issue.. every thing i installed is OK.

Comment: @Angew the exact error is "g++: error: unrecognized option ‘--subsystem,console’"

Comment: Mingw also doesn't seem to use this option. Maybe some conversion from a MSVC project?

Answer (score 1):

This option only have sense if you target Windows (so, you run MinGW or crosscompiling to Windows)

It is not compiler option itself, but linker one. From the `ld` documentation:

> --subsystem which
>   --subsystem which:major
>   --subsystem which:major.minor
>      Specifies the subsystem under which your program will execute.  The
>      legal values for which are "native", "windows", "console", "posix",
>      and "xbox".  You may optionally set the subsystem version also.
>      Numeric values are also accepted for which.  [This option is
>      specific to the i386 PE targeted port of the linker]

If you are *not* crosscompiling or running MinGW, you should configure your IDE or build system to *turn this flag off*.

Otherwise, you should reconfigure IDE or build system to pass this option to the linker, so you should replace

```
--subsystem,console
```

With

```
-Wl,--subsystem,console
```